# Interpretting a group's Mean Residuals when Logged

Tags: residuals, logarithm

Suppose I'm running a regression that looks something like

$$\log(price)=\beta_0 + \beta_1\log(population)+\beta_2\log(population)^2.$$

I have found the residuals, grouped them according to the number of sellers in the observation's town, and calculated the mean residual for each group. Suppose the residuals are 0.05 for 1 seller, -0.01 for 2 sellers, -0.02 for 3 sellers.

I want to make a statement about the %markup to the average price for each group.

Since these are logged residuals, can I just interpret the mean residual as the %markup? (eg. there is a 5% markup from the average price when there is 1 seller, -1% when there are 2, etc.)

Or do I need to use the mean log-price, and then calculate the %change using: $$100 \times \frac{(meanLogPrice+residual)-meanLogPrice}{meanLogPrice} = 100 \times \frac{residual}{meanLogPrice}? $$

Comment: Just a comment: because the number of sellers is likely (strongly positively) correlated with the population, you should instead include the seller groups as a categorical variable in your regression.  The estimated coefficients give the relative effects on log price, which is [interpreted as usual.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+log+interpret+coefficient+-logistic+-logit+is%3Aanswer+score%3A5)